# Tortoise svn version for server version 1.5.5

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn

Which version of tortoise svn should I be using?

- My server version is 1.5.5
- My svn commandline client version is also 1.5.5

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Tortoisesvn has its own internal svn libraries and does not rely on the commandline client on the machine.

If you're going to be working on the same **working copy** with both svn commandline client and tortoisesvn, they need to be at the same point version, either both 1.5 or both 1.6, etc.

If you use tortoisesvn 1.6 to look at a working copy, it will immediately and silently upgrade it to the 1.6 layout. The 1.5 commandline client will then no-longer be able to do any operations on that working copy.

The same is true if you're using 1.6 commandline and 1.5 tortoisesvn.

In terms of communicating with the server, however, there is no problem having 1.6 clients talk to a 1.5 server, or vice versa. 1.6 servers will provide all the features that the 1.5 client expects. 1.6 clients will know that a 1.5 server won't provide the new features and will account for that.

So, you can upgrade your server separate to your clients.
Everyone can upgrade their clients at their own pace.
But everyone should upgrade all the clients on their machine at the same time to avoid tools being locked out of working copies.

Comment: I believe the same is true for 1.4 clients and 1.5 clients. My 1.4 svn commandline client breaks when I use a 1.5 tortoisesvn client.

Answer (score 0):

From the [compatibility matrix](http://tortoisesvn.tigris.org/compatibility.html), the 1.6.x client is compatible with the 1.5.x server (though the newest client functions won't work), so you should probably use the 1.6.5 version of TortoiseSVN (i.e. the latest)

Answer (score 0):

I've never seen subversion break an existing interface when creating new functionality.  This has meant that any tools written for a newer version still work with the old ones.  It also has meant that older tools work with newer versions of subversion.

I recall reading one of their documents about version compatibility stating that "breaking changes" would only be in full number releases.  I guess we better hang on when 2.0 comes out.

I always use the latest version of Tortoise, unless I'm working in a group where there are older versions already installed.  Even then I usually only have to let them know that a newer version exists.  (Free upgrades are nice!)

-- EDIT --
DO check out the "gotcha" by Jim T about needing to keep all of the clients in sync on the same machine.  If you are EVER going to use the command line client, or another client that relies on the command line client, make sure that you use the Tortoise that matches it.

I'd go with the latest of everything if I was starting from scratch.

Answer (score 0):

[The definitive guide](http://subversion.tigris.org/hacking.html#release-numbering) to understanding svn client/server compatiblity.

TortoiseSVN will tell you (TortoiseSVN -> About) what svn client version it was built with.